# how to show lightbox popup on page load in react js

Tags: reactjs, popup

I Want to show pop-up on page load but i don't have knowledge about react javascript . I am using lightbox pop-up . its working fine but its working onclick function . I need to open pop up on page load.
my code is :-

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.0/JSXTransformer.js'></script>
    <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.0/react-with-addons.js'></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src='js/react-lightbox.jsx'></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id='react-canvas'></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        /** @jsx React.DOM */
        React.renderComponent(
            <Lightbox>
                <LightboxTrigger>
                    <a href='javascript:void(0)'>Click me to open!</a>
                </LightboxTrigger>
                <LightboxModal>
                    <div>
                        <h1>This is the basic usage!</h1>
                        <p>Good luck :D</p>
                    </div>
                </LightboxModal>
            </Lightbox>,        

            document.getElementById('react-canvas')
        );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide the link to lightbox doc, that you are referring??

Comment: @MayankShukla this is the link :- http://github.com/howtomakeaturn/React-Lightbox

Comment: Lightbox implementation  you are using is very old, last updated 2 year ago. Try new library maybe [this](https://github.com/fritz-c/react-image-lightbox).

Comment: but its also working onClick button but i need it on page load

Answer (score 0):

Try to create custome elements and add method `this.props.openLightbox` on `componentWillMoutn`

```
   var ToggleButton = React.createClass({
        componentWillMount(){
            this.props.openLightbox();
        }
        render() {
            return(<button onClick={this.props.openLightbox}>Open Lightbox</button>);
        }
    });
```

And put this custom element into `<LightboxTrigger>`

```
<LightboxTrigger>
    <ToggleButton />
</LightboxTrigger>
```

Comment: any other example ?

Comment: it's not compulsory to use lightbox,  I need pop-up on page load using react js ?

Comment: You can create popup based on `state`